# Alfresco Integration with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, alfresco, connector

is there the possibility to integrate Alfresco with an Oracle database not just for metadata?

I need to find a way in order alfresco to point documents persisted like BLOB inside and Oracle Database Table. Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean to have Alfresco store and retrieve the content of files from a DB BLOB, instead of a filesystem as it normally would do? And are you aware that for Oracle support, you need Enterprise and not Community?

Comment: You'd need a custom ContentStore that was Oracle BLOB backed, and an importer which would generate the matching Alfresco content entries to reference the BLOBs. Wouldn't take that long to write and test, I'd guess a day or two. I'd suggest you give Alfresco Sales a ring, they can quote you for both the Enterprise version you'd need, and the consultant to write the importer!

Comment: Exactly... i have a great amount of data in an ucm oracle table. Tera of bytes... it would be very time expensive to move all the docs from ucm to alfresco file System. So i was wondering if it would be possible to.make alfresco to point directly to the datatable as file system. Is there a connector just for the enterprice version? Where is It? And the documentation about it?

Comment: It was one possibility i was thinking about Gagravarr... bbut i m quite new with alfresco...can you suggest me any source code wich i can take as reference?

Comment: It'd be a somewhat advanced feature, so if you're new to Alfresco, it'd be much safer to just cough up for a day or two's Alfresco consultancy to do it for you. Compared to the cost of the Enterprise license fee, it'll be fairly small, and much much simpler!

Comment: Ok thanks for your advice. Just another question... can i develop the custom content store just for the enterprise edittiion? Or even for the community one?

Comment: It'll need to be Enterprise - only Enterprise has support for Oracle databases, so Community won't be able to read or write from an Oracle DB

Comment: @Gagravarr " Wouldn't take that long to write and test, I'd guess a day or two", I am not discussing your ability, but if you can develop such system, with all test completed, performance wise and ready for production after a day or two, you are really a worthy developer, in my case I would take at least three/four days only just for requirements analysis and relative quotation :-D having said that @ Alex, if you have alfresco enterprise I would take a look at AWS S3 connector to have a vague idea of what you need to develop.

Comment: @Leonardo I used to work for Alfresco, and still use it my day job, so I've a fair idea of what's involved! I don't see why one of the Alfresco consulting team wouldn't be able to do it in that time, based on the people there I know and the skills they have. If you're not familiar with the low level Alfresco APIs and interfaces, it would take a lot longer!

Comment: @Gagravarr nothing personal and I am not denying anyone ability, I am just sharing my opinion, limited as you may guess by a still little knowledge on the subject. Of course they are the most skilled people on the market, but as in my experience, I have never encountered a JEE system enhancement ready (I mean ready for production) in a day or two. However, I am curious to hear the quotation from them, once is available.

Comment: @Gagravarr just because you are quite skilled on Alfresco, would you mind to give an eye to this question of mine ? I am still struggling in trying to find an "official" answer to this: [Prevent aspect from being added in share](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294319/prevent-aspect-from-being-added-in-alfresco-share) thanks

Comment: @Leonardo I'm trying to develop my custom solution for using my DBContentStore DBContentWriter and reader as mock up version. I'm in trouble. I used FileContentStore as reference model but in the whol machinism im figuring out that there are more then one method to write in the filesystem. One of them is makeFile in FileContentStore and the CopyStream method which open WritableDirectChannel for writing the content... How do you suggest to develop this method?